# MYSQL Insert query fails with total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

Tags: mysql

The table table1 contains 1500000 rows and contains 80 fields and i want to remove the duplicates based on field1 and field2 and ID field is unique so i used the maximum option.

**Option1:  Insert Option**

```
insert into table2_unique 
select * from table1 a
where  a.id = ( select max(b.id) from table1 b
               where a.field1 = b.field1
               and a.field2 = b.field2 );
```

But the query fails because of the below error.

```
Error Code: 1206. The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size
```

Explain Statement:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   INSERT  table2  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   PRIMARY a   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1387764 100 Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  b   NULL    ref field1x,field2x field1x 39  a.field1    537 10  Using where
```

**Option2 DELETE Statement:**

```
DELETE n1 FROM table1 n1, table1 n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.field1 = n2.field1 and n1.field2 and n2.field2
```

When i execute then Deadlock occured.

I am not able to increase the buffer pool size, please let me know shall i write the query in different way.

Comment: Where's your delete statement?

Comment: DELETE Statement also posted

Comment: 80 fields? Sounds like your lack of a properly defined primary key isn't your only problem.

Comment: Do you intend to delete from both tables?

Comment: Finally found the way to change the INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE and the query ran in 27 mins

Comment: Sloan thrasher - It will delete only table1

Answer (score 1):

Increased the INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE in my.ini file and the query ran in 27 mins for that specified volume

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it will impact the locks but using dependant sub-queries (i.e. pushed predicates) in mysql has never worked very well in my experience. I would have written the first query as:

```
insert into table2_unique (id, col1, col2, ...col79)
select a.id, a.col1, a.col2, ...a.col79
from table1 a
Inner join (
   Select max(b.id) as id
   From table1 b
   Group by b.col1, b.col2
 ) As dedup
 On a.id=dedup.id;
```

Trying to update a table using a join is always a bit dodgy. When its a self-join, then its not surprising it fails. Using a temporary table and splitting the operation into 2 steps avoids this.